# Saving and looping using vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to save as a PDF a section of an Excel sheet that is based from the information in another sheet of the workbook.

The first sheet in which I got to print in a PDF the section A1:I23 is named Enveloppe.
The second sheet in which the data is stored is named Info-Cas.

Basically, I made a table that I have to export as a PDF and merge every of the 144 PDF together. Of course, I don't want to type everyting one by one so I wrote the following macro. Obviously, it does not work right now.

```
Dim FName As String
Dim i As Integer

FName = Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("K1").Text

For i = 2 To 4

    'Copier la journée du cas
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("K" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Copier les informations principales (Cas, Numéro d'équipe, Salle)
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("A" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("B" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("C" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("D" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("E" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Copier les informations sur l'horaire
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("F" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("G" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("H" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("I" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Info-Cas").Range("J" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("B14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    'Enregistrer le document au format PDF
    Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("A1:I23").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=FName
Next
```

The problem I have is that, for the sample I tried, only the last PDF is saving right now.

Also, I'd like to save the file in a certain folder on my computer. Can anyone help me doing those?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: becuase you are not updating your filename inside the for loop.

Comment: The name is updating itself in the K1 cell using the information from B4 and B5. Is-it still possible or do I have to copy in a third sheet and print out only once?

Answer (score 0):

now, you r save the file 3 times. 
first you need to copy the data on a sheet 'Enveloppe'

```
for i = 2 To 4
next
```

then save the file:

```
Worksheets("Enveloppe").Range("A1:I23").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=FName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy/paste method is very inefficient.

See if this works (untested):

```
'Your worksheet variables
Dim wsInfoCas As Worksheet, wsEnveloppe As Worksheet
Set wsInfoCas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info-Cas")
Set wsEnveloppe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enveloppe")

'Your copy variable
Dim retVal, retArr1(), retArr2()

For i = 2 To 4

    FName = wsEnveloppe.Range("K1").Text

    With wsInfoCas

        retVal = .Range("K" & i).Value
        retArr1 = .Range("A" & i, "E" & i).Value
        retArr2 = .Range("F" & i, "J" & i).Value

    End With

    With Application.WorksheetFunction

        wsEnveloppe.Range("A3").Value = retVal
        wsEnveloppe.Range("B4:B8").Value = .Transpose( _
                retArr1)
        wsEnveloppe.Range("B10:B14").Value = .Transpose( _
                retArr2)
    End With

Next

wsEnveloppe.Range("A1:I23").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=FName
```